# How to optimize and check for N+1 DB Queries in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I believe I have an N + 1 issue but I want to see if anyone can give any suggestions on how to optimize this because my code is running way too many queries.

**controllers/profit_reports_controller.rb**

```
def weekly
 @sales = Sale.by_category(@category).this_week(@beg_of_week)
 @departments = Department.by_category(@category)
end
```

**profit_reports/weekly.html.erb**

```
<% @departments.each do |department| %>
  <% @stores.each do |store| %>
    <% @sale = @sales.by_store(store).by_department(department).sum(:amount) %>
```

**models/sale.rb**

```
#Associations
belongs_to :store
belongs_to :department

#Scopes
scope :by_category, lambda {|category| where(:category_id => category.id)}
scope :by_department, lambda {|department| where(:department_id => department.id)}
scope :by_store, lambda {|store| where(:store_id => store.id)}
scope :this_week, lambda {|beg_of_week| where(:date_of_sale =>  beg_of_week..beg_of_week + 6.days)}
```

Comment: What is the relationship between your models? Show us in your code.

Comment: What does the query optimizer (of whatever RDBMS you're using) tell you?

Comment: I am sorry if I was very general. I just updated the code with the model of sale. I have not run any query optimizer yet I was first looking for suggestions. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest using the [Bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) gem. From the repo:

> The Bullet gem is designed to help you increase your application’s
>   performance by reducing the number of queries it makes. It will watch
>   your queries while you develop your application and notify you when
>   you should add eager loading (N+1 queries), when you’re using eager
>   loading that isn’t necessary and when you should use counter cache.

It will also tell you how to fix it. Have fun!

Comment: That was my next step! Thanks